# React onClick Event Not Working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make the onClick event working in React but with no luck. I cannot figure out what is wronge

```
var Item = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    return <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
});

var ItemList= React.createClass({
handleClick: function(i){
    console.log("clicked",i)
},
renderListItems: function() {
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var text = "item " + i;
    list.push( <Item key={i} text={text} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,i)} /> )

  }
  return list;
},

render: function() { 

  return (
    <div> 
    {
      this.renderListItems()
    } 
    </div>
  )
}});


ReactDOM.render(
  <ItemList />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Any idea why it is not working ?

Here is a demo for the code above https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/55485/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass your `onClick` handler through to the `div` in your `Item` component:

```
var Item = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` handler is not mentioned in the `Item` component.

```
var Item = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
});
```

updated working fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/55503/